# Cache at Single request Id level where an API request is for different set of RequestIds

Tags: caching, spring-cache

I have a requirement where the request to a product API will have Multiple Product Ids, and this set of Ids in request can be different for each request.

Given the scenario, if I need to cache the product data with product Id as a key, is it possible with Spring Cache?

Ex:

Request1 - prod1, prod2, prod3, ....
Cache created - {prod1=D1, prod2=G1, prod3=B3}

Request2 - prod4, prod5, prod2, ....

prod2 - value fetched from cache and
Cache updated with new data set for prod4 and prod5

Please note we cannot afford to make single API calls for product service. One approach is not to use spring cache, instead build a Map of information as below.

****Map<String, String> productCategoryMap;

getProductCategories(List products) {

//return data from cache and/or loaded cache when data not found in productCategoryMap

}

loadProductCategories(List products);****

Please comment your thoughts on the problem statement and possible ways of implementing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Guava Caching fits in to be best solution for this Usecase.
I used loadAll(..) for a list of product ids.

The issue here is getAll(..) fails/throws exception when No Data found for a given product id, this can handled by catching the exception and then calling getAllPresent(..)